# getting error 'assetmanager.process is not a function' while trying to start node server

Tags: node.js, mean-stack, mean.io

I am trying to run MEAN stack, I am trying to start Node server by running `node server` command,

> `TypeError: assetmanager.process is not a function
>       at configureApp (C:\Users\Harsh\first\node_modules\meanio\lib\core_modules\module\aggregation.js:401:29)
>       at Consumer.Dependable.runAction (C:\Users\Harsh\first\node_modules\lazy-dependable\index.js:73:22)
>       at Consumer.Dependable.fire (C:\Users\Harsh\first\node_modules\lazy-dependable\index.js:70:53)
>       at Consumer.onResolved (C:\Users\Harsh\first\node_modules\lazy-dependable\index.js:120:8)
>       at Consumer.Dependable.resolve (C:\Users\Harsh\first\node_modules\lazy-dependable\index.js:56:10)
>       at Meanio.Container.notifyResolved (C:\Users\Harsh\first\node_modules\lazy-dependable\index.js:209:7)
>       at Dependency.onResolved (C:\Users\Harsh\first\node_modules\lazy-dependable\index.js:105:18)
>       at Dependency.Dependable.resolve (C:\Users\Harsh\first\node_modules\lazy-dependable\index.js:56:10)
>       at Meanio.Container.register (C:\Users\Harsh\first\node_modules\lazy-dependable\index.js:167:5)
>       at C:\Users\Harsh\first\node_modules\meanio\lib\core_modules\db\index.js:101:20
>       at open (C:\Users\Harsh\first\node_modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:488:17)
>       at NativeConnection.Connection.onOpen (C:\Users\Harsh\first\node_modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:498:5)
>       at C:\Users\Harsh\first\node_modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:457:10
>       at C:\Users\Harsh\first\node_modules\mongoose\lib\drivers\node-mongodb-native\connection.js:60:5
>       at C:\Users\Harsh\first\node_modules\mongodb\lib\db.js:229:5
>       at connectHandler (C:\Users\Harsh\first\node_modules\mongodb\lib\server.js:279:7)
>       at g (events.js:260:16)
>       at emitOne (events.js:77:13)
>       at emit (events.js:169:7)
>       at C:\Users\Harsh\first\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\topologies\server.js:409:23
>       at C:\Users\Harsh\first\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\topologies\server.js:778:13
>       at Callbacks.emit (C:\Users\Harsh\first\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\topologies\server.js:95:3)
>   C:\Users\Harsh\first\node_modules\mongodb\lib\server.js:282
>         process.nextTick(function() { throw err; })
>                                       ^
>
> TypeError: assetmanager.process is not a function
>       at configureApp (C:\Users\Harsh\first\node_modules\meanio\lib\core_modules\module\aggregation.js:401:29)
>       at Consumer.Dependable.runAction (C:\Users\Harsh\first\node_modules\lazy-dependable\index.js:73:22)
>       at Consumer.Dependable.fire (C:\Users\Harsh\first\node_modules\lazy-dependable\index.js:70:53)
>       at Consumer.onResolved (C:\Users\Harsh\first\node_modules\lazy-dependable\index.js:120:8)
>       at Consumer.Dependable.resolve (C:\Users\Harsh\first\node_modules\lazy-dependable\index.js:56:10)
>       at Meanio.Container.notifyResolved (C:\Users\Harsh\first\node_modules\lazy-dependable\index.js:209:7)
>       at Dependency.onResolved (C:\Users\Harsh\first\node_modules\lazy-dependable\index.js:105:18)
>       at Dependency.Dependable.resolve (C:\Users\Harsh\first\node_modules\lazy-dependable\index.js:56:10)
>       at Meanio.Container.register (C:\Users\Harsh\first\node_modules\lazy-dependable\index.js:167:5)
>       at C:\Users\Harsh\first\node_modules\meanio\lib\core_modules\db\index.js:101:20
>       at open (C:\Users\Harsh\first\node_modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:488:17)
>       at NativeConnection.Connection.onOpen (C:\Users\Harsh\first\node_modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:498:5)
>       at C:\Users\Harsh\first\node_modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:457:10
>       at C:\Users\Harsh\first\node_modules\mongoose\lib\drivers\node-mongodb-native\connection.js:60:5
>       at C:\Users\Harsh\first\node_modules\mongodb\lib\db.js:229:5
>       at connectHandler (C:\Users\Harsh\first\node_modules\mongodb\lib\server.js:279:7)
>       at g (events.js:260:16)
>       at emitOne (events.js:77:13)
>       at emit (events.js:169:7)
>       at C:\Users\Harsh\first\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\topologies\server.js:409:23
>       at C:\Users\Harsh\first\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\topologies\server.js:778:13
>       at Callbacks.emit (C:\Users\Harsh\first\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\topologies\server.js:95:3)

Also used `gulp` command still same error, where am I going wrong??

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar error when there was an issue with the git clone. Re-clone the repository and then run on your console:

```
git clone https://github.com/meanjs/mean.git myprojectname
npm install
bower install
```

The install processes will take a little while but running `gulp` after this should work.